# Using Mongo Map Reduce for Notification System

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm implementing a notification system in mongodb. Basically I create notification items and subscribe users on them. After that if any actions happen on notification items, I just log them in action document so i can query user's notifications on action collection.
So far it's all good.

Now I just want to group actions by their type and notification items and sort the result by latest action time (let say follow, comment, like). So i can make summary like "John, Lisa and 3 other like your bla bla"

To succeed it I implemented mapreduce on mongodb. It's also working. But the problem is it doesnt look right;

Because mapreduce generates a collection as output.
In this case;

User1 login, mapreduce run generate notification collection then
User2 login, mapreduce run generate notification collection with same name(which already created for another user).

I'm curios about what happens if multiple users trigger the mapreduce at the same time?(which is quite possible,it's a social network)

I thought that maybe i can create unique notification collections for each user `notification_$userid` .. For 1M users 1M collection doesnt sound right?

By the way I started with the MongoDB grouping but changed to mapreduce because i want to sort result set.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't follow your example. Are you creating new collections for each user or reusing? If reusing, it's just going to overwrite other collections. By default, you can't have more than 25000 collections. If you did have a collection per user, and used incremental MapReduce, you may have situations where the MapReduce data collection isn't up to date for a given user.

Comment: MRs are not good to be run inline to your application, I would personally consider it a fundamental flaw in your logic to run a MR inline to the user waiting for the page to load. Instead you should try and design a schema to do this, that's what I did...

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm not creating a collection for each user, mapreduce's result should be unique for each user in my case. that's the problem, i couldnt figure out.

Comment: @Sammaye I see your point. And it makes sense, that's why i'm not comfortable with my current design. My initial schema can provide basic functionality, I can query basically with find. Then what solution can you suggest for grouping similar actions on similar items?

Comment: It depends on how you write the notifications atm. If you write a notification per user then it can be quite simple to group pre-emptively, i.e. you could query for where this user is sending a notification to that user that has already been performed. If it has then add this user to a list of `user_ids` in that event document and then on display calculate the length of the `user_ids` field and render say 3 users from it.

Comment: @Sammaye i'm creating a single event document for just event owner.. each user create their own event.

Comment: Hmm you might wanna shift that schema around so that users "send" each other notifications. This is how most sites handle this kind of interaction.

Comment: ok i see. any reference link or simple conceptual answer would be helpful for me and others :)